# Android preference non-deprecated onClickListener

Tags: android, onclick, listener, preference, setting

I've recently started coding an app and I've come to add preferences.
Now I need some kind of non-deprecated onClickListener.
I want to be able to clear a set of SharedPreferences using this preference which should be handled as a button. Is that possible to do in any way AND being compatible with android 2.3 and up?

XML:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Technisch" >

    <Preference
        android:key="force_update"
        android:title="Force update" />

    <Preference
        android:key="clear_settings"
        android:title="Reset antwoorden">
    </Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I would like to do something like getPreference("clear_settings").addOnClickListener(this);
but all functions i've found either don't allow code execution OR are deprecated...

Comment: What do you mean by non deprecated onClickListener ? What is that you are trying to implement ?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to when you say "non-depreciated onClickListener"??  If you could be a little more specific and post the code that you are having issues with we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Third'd.  This doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: What doesn't make sense? I just want a Preference onClickListener that is not deprecated

Comment: What do you mean by a Preference onClickListener?

Comment: Once again, without your source code it is difficult to help.  I'm guessing getPreference returns a string?  typically you set a listener to a GUI widget such as a button..

Comment: getPreference() does not exist, but I want some method that listens for a touchEvent on touching the Preference. (preference is a display object, the thing you see in a lot of setting pages, with the scrollable lists)